# What is the "legendary Chicago machine" Rosenfeld refers to in his 1963 paper *On quantization of fields*?

Tags: physics, quote, social-context, 20th-century

There's a famous paper by L. Rosenfeld (On quantization of fields. *Nuclear Physics* **40**, 353–356 (1963). doi:[10.1016/0029-5582(63)90279-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/0029-5582(63)90279-7)) in which he criticizes the theoretical arguments leading to the conclusion that gravity must be quantized, stating that experimental is what really matters in the end of the day. It ends with the following quote:

> The preceding hints may suffice to expose the inanity of a reasoning which amounts to putting physics upside down. It is nice to have at one's disposal such exquisite
> mathematical tools as the present methods of quantum field theory, but one should
> not forget that these methods have been elaborated in order to describe definite
> empirical situations, in which they find their only justification. Any question as to
> their range of application can only be answered by experience, not by formal argumentation. Even the legendary Chicago machine cannot deliver the sausages if it is
> not supplied with hogs.

I've seen this quote or references to it in a number of references (e.g., arXiv: [0803.3456 [gr-qc]](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3456), arXiv: [2201.10452 [gr-qc]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.10452), [this text by N. Hugget and C. Callender](https://huggett.people.uic.edu/Nick/My%20Work_files/why.pdf), and others I can't recall). Now, I would like to know what *is* the "legendary Chicago machine" Rosenfeld refers to. While it might initially sound silly since he only uses it as an analogy, I consider this interesting since while a possibility could be "It just happens that Chicago is famous for its sausages" (I have no clue if that's the case and I couldn't discover it), another one which is much deeper is that he's criticizing some school of thought that was then frequent in the University of Chicago, for example (once again, I'm speculating for the sake of an example, I couldn't discover if this is the case).

In short, what is the Chicago machine he refers to?

While I've been in Physics.SE for a while, this is my first question in History of Science and Mathematics, so if I'm failing in following any of the site's usual guidelines for questioning please let me know.

Comment: Wild guess: maybe it's a reference to [Chicago Pile-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Pile-1)?

Comment: Or maybe a reference to the poem _Chicago_ by Carl Sandburg, whose first line is "Hog Butcher for the World?"

Comment: "Chicago machine" has a specific meaning within American politics, but the reference to hogs makes clear that this is *not* meant here, but rather that this is a reference to the giant stockyards and meat packing plants for which Chicago was famous roughly from 1870 to 1970. I don't have time to look for appropriate references right now. In 1906 Upton Sinclair published a famous novel "The Jungle" which deals in part with the horrific conditions then prevalent in the Chicago meat industry.

Comment: @njuffa has it right - that is a reference to the Chicago meatpacking industry. Maybe this should be marked as Spam (but Spam is made in Minnesota, not Chicago) (tongue firmly in cheek).